# How to Remember Sign In in Google Account Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, google-signin

**Login Activity**
Please Help I just wanted to Remember Login in App in background, so that when he reopen the app automatically next activity open rather than sign in activity.

```
package xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx;

/**
 * Created by Yoyo on 12/21/2015.
 */
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    SignInButton signIn_btn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    ProgressDialog progress_dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        buidNewGoogleApiClient();
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        customizeSignBtn();
        setBtnClickListeners();
        progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress_dialog.setMessage("Signing in....");
    }

    /*
    Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile.
    User's ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    create and  initialize GoogleApiClient object to use Google  Sign-In API and the options specified by gso..
    */

    private void buidNewGoogleApiClient(){

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this )
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    /*
      Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
      multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
      rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
      be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
      may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
      Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN scope to see the  difference.
    */

    private void customizeSignBtn(){

        signIn_btn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signIn_btn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signIn_btn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    }

    /*
      Set on click Listeners on the sign-in sign-out and disconnect buttons
     */

    private void setBtnClickListeners(){
        // Button listeners
        signIn_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                progress_dialog.dismiss();

            }
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            getSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "start sign process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignIn();
                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Sign Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Access Revoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gRevokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void gSignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        progress_dialog.show();
    }

    private void gSignOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });
    }

    private void gRevokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });
    }

    private void getSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {



            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            TextView user_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
            TextView email_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
            user_name.setText("UserName: "+ acct.getDisplayName());
            email_id.setText("Email Id: " + acct.getEmail());
            updateUI(true);        

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
            editor.putString("name", //Name),
             editor.putString("e_mail",
                            editor.putString("ID", //ID);
                                    editor.commit());



   progress_dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Login xml file for the Activity **login xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="num.app.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.Login"
    tools:showIn="@layout/Login">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" user name:"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="email id:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Google Sign out"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="revoke Google Access"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//Splash activity before the above activity

```
   Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try{
                    sleep(1000);

                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{



                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("android.intent.action.Login");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

Comment: The information which you get, you can store it in `SharedPreference` to avoid further login. And if the user logout of the application, you can clear the `SharedPreference` data.

Comment: @NigamPatro Can you just do some amendments in coding to show me what to do ?

Comment: Do you have Splash Screen in application?

Comment: @NigamPatro
Yes at first Activity it was Splash Screen which open the Login Activity

Comment: So, which part you are unable to understand?

Comment: @NigamPatro I want when I login , then next time when I open app it will not ask to login again but show the next activity page to show its name that's it.

Comment: Where you are redirecting to which activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

After user login success then you can save id token to SharedPreferences by call method getIdToken() of GoogleSignInAccount. And when user reopen you can check id token is exiting then ignore login screen.

```
private void getSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            String id_token = acct.getIdToken(); //add this code here to save it by use SharedPreferences 

            TextView user_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
            TextView email_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
            user_name.setText("UserName: "+ acct.getDisplayName());
            email_id.setText("Email Id: " + acct.getEmail());
            updateUI(true);
            progress_dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

//save user login state id_token

private void saveLoginState(String id_token){

   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("GG_LOGED", id_token);

            editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: Let me try this , then I will get back to you.

Comment: I want when I login , then next time when I open app it will not ask to login again but show the next activity page to show its name that's it.
can u do tht for me PLEASE

Comment: @RajKaran do you try this code to save to SharedPreferences:

Comment: @RajKaran have just update my code above so you can try again

Comment: see when I login and all details are fetched, but when i clear the app from memory and start the app again it shows me login page again, I don't wnt to see login with google again but all details that I got from login.

Like when you sign in google account and close it and clear the memory and after that you can see the news feed rather than sign in process.

Comment: oh. i think you don't. you can try clear for some app (facebook, gmail,...) still require login again.. and i don't understand why you would like clear app for your case... i am confusing!

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid saving the token in the shared preferences and rather try to perform a Silent Sign In as described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html

This has the advantage to let you verify if the user is still logged in and eventually let you prompt him to request to re-login.

here some code (basically adapted from the example in the link):

```
public void silentLogin() {
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
    if (pendingResult != null) {
        handleGooglePendingResult(pendingResult);
    } else {
        //no result from silent login. Possibly display the login page again 
    }
}

private void handleGooglePendingResult(OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult) {
    if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
        // There's immediate result available.
        GoogleSignInResult signInResult = pendingResult.get();
        onSilentSignInCompleted(signInResult);
    } else {
        // There's no immediate result ready,  waits for the async callback.
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult signInResult) {
                onSilentSignInCompleted(signInResult, callback);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void onSilentSignInCompleted(GoogleSignInResult signInResult) {
    GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = signInResult.getSignInAccount();        
    if (signInAccount != null) {
            // you have a valid sign in account. Skip the login.

        } else {
            // you don't have a valid sign in account. Eventually display the login page again
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the user login you can use this code to store the data in `SharedPreference`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
editor.putString("name", //Name);
editor.putString("e_mail",//Email);
editor.putString("ID", //ID);
editor.commit();
```

And in the splash screen you can do like this

```
boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);
```

Here `isLoggedIn` is the value whether the user is logged in or not status. You need to handle this in SplashScreen and proceed according to that.

Comment: I have edited it and added splash activity code which open the Login activity, now I am confuse where to put above code

Comment: **I have already placed**
boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);"
 **in finally but Where to put below code**

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
editor.putString("name", //Name);
editor.putString("e_mail",//Email);
editor.putString("ID", //ID);
editor.commit();

Comment: In the method `getSignInResult` inside if condition.

Comment: There is problem in semicolon of  editor.commit();  
//Showing error  ')' expected
I have put parenthesis but still error

Comment: @RajKaran Modify your this code `editor.putString("e_mail",
                            editor.putString("ID", //ID); editor.putString("ID", //ID);` into  `editor.putString("name", acct.getDisplayName());
        editor.putString("e_mail", acct.getEmail());
        editor.putString("ID", acct.getIdToken());
        editor.commit();`

Comment: **I put the code**
 Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("android.intent.action.Login");
                        startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                        finish();

**then write the below code , but it is showing msg isLoggedin not use**
 boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);

Comment: This is reasn I was confused , mean how could I do that ?
So what can I do to solve this !! Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98559/discussion-between-nigam-patro-and-raj-karan).